# Why does it return normal weight

Tags: javascript, return

This BMI calculator returns it right for the underweight and the normal weight, but when `result` is bigger than 25 it returns the normal weight option, when it's supposed to return the overweight option. How can I fix it?

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
  var weight = prompt("How much do you weight?")
  var height = prompt("How tall are you?  ")

  result = weight / Math.pow(height, 2)

  if (result < 18.5) {
    return("Your BMI is " + result + " , so you are underweight")
  } else if (result >= 18.5 || result <= 24.9) {
    return("Your BMI is " + result + ", so you have a normal weight")
  } else if (result >= 25) {
    return("Your BMI is " + result + ", so you are overweight")
  }
}

console.log(bmiCalculator())
```

Comment: If you use cm and kg, you need to multiply by 10000: `let result = +(weight / Math.pow(height, 2)*10000).toFixed(2)` Also use AND `&&` instead of OR `||`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the || to an &&

Instead of:

```
} else if (result >= 18.5 || result <= 24.9) {
```

Do:

```
} else if (result >= 18.5 && result <= 24.9) {
```